# SIP and RTP in VoLTE

Tags: sip, lte, 4g

I am investigating the SIP signaling and RTP media in VoLTE traffic. I can see RTP header but was told that the RTP payload and the SIP packets are all encrypted in IPsec. Is this true? If yes, at what interface I can see the decrypted packets?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it isn't about programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LTE is based on IMS (IP Multimedia Subsystem) which is a very broad and encompassing set of specifications for an architectural framework that enables multimedia communication between IP connected end points.

Because it is so broad and all encompassing there are actually many different security points and interfaces - for example there are security specs for communication between an access network connected device (such as a mobile phone) and the core, for communication between different nodes within a single core network, for communication between different operator's or organisation's core networks etc.

3GPP and LTE build on the IMS specs and include specific security specs for the Mobile world also. There is a 3GPP spec which looks at access security for IMS (3GPP TS 33.203) and it includes the following diagram:

[image]

Each of the numbers in the diagram above is a different security 'association' and the above standard references one or more specifications for each one.

The result of all this security complexity and these many security layers is that the answer to your question depends on the point in the network you are looking at. For example, if you intercept the traffic between the phone and the base station you will not be able to see anything as it will all be encrypted at a lower layer (notwithstanding the latest GSM/3G security hacks etc). Similarly if you are looking at the traffic between the core network nodes or between different networks this may be over IPSEC tunnels etc and again you will not be able to see it.

If your aim is to intercept and eavesdrop on VoLTE voice calls then you are going to find this very hard as many of the above mechanisms are designed to prevent this - I won't say it is impossible as I'm sure someone will reference a hack or a 'government backdoor' example for similar technology etc.

If your interest is academic, or in profiling the performance of the network etc then you may be able to achieve what you want using one of the open source IMS solutions - e.g. http://www.openimscore.org.

Or, if you are working for, or with, one of the network equipment vendors then you may be in a position to insert or leverage network management and/or OSS 'hooks' or mechanisms which allow you gather info from some unencrypted data at certain points in the end to end flow.

Comment: I've posted a question about how to extract the parameter **correlation number** out of the HI2 datafile (SIP) of VoICE. Could You pls. have a look? Thanks in advance 4 Your help. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60598809/name-of-parameter-correlation-number-between-cc-and-iri-in-iri-datafile-voice-o]